# How to put an ellipsis at the end of TextView containing two lines

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `TextView` in Android and I want to put an ellipsis (". . .") at the end of the `TextView` when there are more characters in the text than the size of the `TextView` (i.e. when the entire text cannot be displayed in the `TextView`).

I know the solution when there is one line in the `TextView`:

```
singleLine="true" and maxLines="1"
```

However, I have two lines in my `TextView`.

Answer (score 7):

```
 android:ellipsize="end" for ...end of text
```

Answer (score 1):

there is a `setEllipsize` method on the textview,

which takes a parameter of:

```
TextUtils.TruncateAt END

TextUtils.TruncateAt MARQUEE

TextUtils.TruncateAt MIDDLE

TextUtils.TruncateAt START
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following attribute in `textview`

```
android:ellipsize="end"
maxLines="2"
```